# KL divergence between two univariate Poisson distributions

Tags: distributions, kullback-leibler

I found this awesome thread which shows KL divergence between two univariate Gaussians. I was wondering if the same formula worked for KL divergence b/w 2 univariate Poisson distributions.

Or should I use the general KL divergence formula and plug into it the pdf for a Poisson process:
$$\int { pdf1(x)*{ log(pdf1(x)/pdf2(x))} } $$

where for Poisson is $$pdf(x) = (\lambda^x / x!)*e^{-\lambda} $$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is fairly straight-foward.  The log ratio of the densities is equal to:

$$ \log\left (\frac {f_1}{f_2}\right)=x\log\left (\frac {\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\right)+\lambda_2-\lambda_1$$

Then you take expectation of this expression wrt $ f_1$, which simply replaces $ x $ with its expectation (in this case).   So you have:

$$ D_{KL} (f_1||f_2)=\lambda_1\log\left (\frac {\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\right)+\lambda_2-\lambda_1$$